# Accept file upload (without a form) in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, postman

I have this Sinatra::Base code:

```
class Crush < Sinatra::Base
  post '/upload' do
    erb params.inspect
  end
end
```

I am using Postman and its interface for uploading a file. So I send a POST request with `form-data`, where in the body of the request the name is `hello` and the value is a file `test.txt` which contains just a simple string `hey there`.

When I do `params.inspect` I get this long string

{"------WebKitFormBoundaryocOEEr26iZGSe75n\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name"=>"\"hello\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nhey there\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryocOEEr26iZGSe75n--\r\n"}

So basically a long has with a single key and a single value. Reading most Sinatra tutorials (where the file is accepted from a form), there's a nice way Sinatra handles this using `params[:file]`, but this doesn't seem to be the case when the file is coming straight from the body of an HTTP request.

I tried a non-modular approach too withou `Sinatra::Base`, thinking it's some parsing middle-ware missing, but got the same result.

Is there something I'm missing here? Must I go and make my own custom parser to get the content of this long hash? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it's Postman issue. When I switch from 'x-www-form-urlencoded' to 'form-data' in Postman, in the Header section, the field: `Content-Type => application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is NOT removed. So for those who encounter this problem, make sure you remove it manually.